# Django: access form argument in CreateView to pass to get_success_url

Tags: django, python-3.x

**I use CreateView to let a user create a Piece. The Piece will automatically be assigned an id.** After the user created the Piece I would like to redirect using get_success_url to another CreateView to add Versions of the Piece.
First of all, I do not know where the id of the Piece comes from (since it is generated automatically; I imagine this is the row number of the Piece in the model). **How can I access this id to pass it to get_success_url?**
The get_context_data method in CreateView seems not to be able to get the Piece id.

**views.py**

```
class PieceCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Piece
    fields = ['title', 'summary', 'created', 'piece_type']
    initial = {'created': datetime.date.today()}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = Creator.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return super(PieceCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PieceCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context['id']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('pieceinstance-create', kwargs={'pk': self.get_context_data()})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('pieceinstance/create/<int:pk>', views.PieceInstanceCreate.as_view(), name='pieceinstance-create')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instance that is constructed in the `CreateView` can be accessed with [**`self.object`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.object), so you can obtain the primary key with `self.object.pk`:

```
class PieceCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Piece
    fields = ['title', 'summary', 'created', 'piece_type']
    initial = {'created': datetime.date.today()}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = Creator.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return super(PieceCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('pieceinstance-create', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

I would advice *not* to override the `get_context_data` function that way: first of all, the contract specifies that it should return a `dict`ionary, so not an id, and multiple functions make use of this, and expect the contract to be satisfied.

Comment: thank you very much for clarifying and making my code lighter.